# How to remove extra space from top and bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I am using auto growable div to display code. It shows a line of space above the code and a line of space below the code. I want to remove it. I tried my best but failed. Can you please help it. I thank you for your all support. Here is image of how it looks -
[image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLIFV.png)

This is my code

```css
.code{
    background-color: #d1e0e0;
    font-family: 'Microsoft New Tai Lue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="code" id="text">
            <xmp>
                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                This is a simple HTML page
                            </body>
                        </html>
            </xmp>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to put ur code in codepen or fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the spacing in the html.

```css
.code{
background-color: #d1e0e0;
font-family: 'Microsoft New Tai Lue', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="code" id="text">
        <xmp>                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            This is a simple HTML page
                        </body>
                    </html></xmp>            
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

give margin and padding 0px

```
element { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this if your okay with it. Hope it helps you. Thank you.

```css
.code{
    background-color: #d1e0e0;
    font-family: 'Microsoft New Tai Lue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
xmp {
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="code" id="text">
            <xmp>
                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                This is a simple HTML page
                            </body>
                        </html>
            </xmp>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

or you can use negetive margin like

```
xmp{margin:-15px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
xmp {
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```